# Is Magog associated with Germany?

Tags: sources-mekorot, targumin, prophecies, messianic-redemption

Bereshit 10:2 reads:

> בְּנֵ֣י יֶ֔פֶת גֹּ֣מֶר וּמָג֔וֹג וּמָדַ֖י וְיָוָ֣ן וְתֻבָ֑ל וּמֶ֖שֶׁךְ
> וְתִירָֽס׃

Targum Jonathan to this verse reads:

> בְּנוֹי דְיֶפֶת גוֹמֶר וּמָגוֹג וּמָדַי וְיָוָן וְתוּבָל וּמֶשֶׁךְ וְתִירָס וְשׁוּם אַפַּרְכְיוּתְהוֹן אַפְרִיקֵיוְגַרְמַנְיָא וְתַמְדִיֵי וּמַקֵדוֹנִיָא וְיַתִינְיָא וְאוּסְיָא וְתַרְקֵי

Thus, the author of the Targum associates Magog with a place called "Germania".

I did some research, and indeed in the time period that the Targum was written, Germania did already refer to the region of modern day Germany, and was a roman province.

With the events of WW2 and the subsequent founding of Israel, the connection between Germany and the apocalyptical place Magog is very fascinating.

Are there any sources that make this connection and discuss in detail the ramifications of interpreting the Gog Umagog Prophecies in this fashion based on the Targum?

Comment: I don't think "the apocalyptical place Magog" is the site prophesied about. It says ביום בוא גוג על אדמת ישראל

Comment: @ba Gog comes from Magog. 
בֶּן־אָדָ֗ם שִׂ֤ים פָּנֶ֙יךָ֙ אֶל־גּוֹג֙ אֶ֣רֶץ הַמָּג֔וֹג נְשִׂ֕יא רֹ֖אשׁ מֶ֣שֶׁךְ וְתֻבָ֑ל וְהִנָּבֵ֖א עָלָֽיו׃

Comment: Thats from Yechezkel 38:2 BTW

Comment: Much more likely in my opinion to be referring to the Persian province of Germania (know today as [Kerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerman_Province))

Comment: The existence of 2 'Germanys' is the reason you find reference to גרממיא/גרמניא של אדום when Chazal are referring to the Roman (European) province.

Comment: Side note: Some say ראש is Russia. The Russians were originally called the Rus people.